# fixing focus out on pressing a "esc" key

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user clicks on a search box, the user sees a "blinking cursor" inside the search box.

I'd like, when the user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, the "blinking cursor" should leave search box and also focus out from search box.

I need JavaScript code to do it.

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon .ng');
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0 .s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0 .s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text] :ocus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
<p>Animated search form :/p>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search .">
</form>
```

Comment: function keyCode(event) {
    var esckeyp = event.keyCode;
    if (esckeyp == 27) {


    }
}

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `document.getElementById("search").blur()` when "esc" is pressed works just fine, where "search" is an id given to the search box.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {//27 is the code for escape
        document.getElementById("search").blur(); 
    }
};
```

```css
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Animated search form:</p>

<form>
  <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned jQuery - here is the solution for that.

```js
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) $(this).blur(); 
});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Animated search form:</p>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```